# Can not get an Environmental Variable that is defined in BASH and exported to show up in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment-variables

I have uses nano .bash_profile, then I added a line - export OBN_KEY='blahblahblah' and saved it and exited and when I use printenv in the terminal it is on the list. How ever when I go over to IDLE and import os and print(os.environ) it does not show up on that list I am using python 3.7, what am I missing? I am also new to coding so I may be missing something simple but pls help.

Comment: Was IDLE invoked from a bash shell?  If not, then your bash profile will not affect its environment.

Comment: To invoke IDLE from shell, just type: `python3 -m idlelib.idle`.

Comment: perfect that worked thank you!